# Unable to display a Rotating Triangular Pyramid

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, webgl

**Objective:** I am trying to display a Triangular Pyramid with different
perspective views as you change the values  of  zNear,  zFar, radius, theta, phi, fov, and aspect through the corresponding sliders. and the buttons rotate x,y,z is to rotate the pyramid on different axis.

**Issue:** So far I came up with the below code, everything looks in place but I don't see the pyramid, it errors out when I try to display the HTML file.

```js
var canvas;
var gl;

var NumVertices  = 12;

var pointsArray = [];
var colorsArray = [];

var xAxis = 0;
var yAxis = 1;
var zAxis = 2;

var axis = 0;
var theta = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

var near = 0.3;
var far = 3.0;
var radius = 4.0;
var theta  = 0.0;
var phi    = 0.0;
var dr = 5.0 * Math.PI/180.0;

//var thetaLoc;

var  fovy = 45.0;  // Field-of-view in Y direction angle (in degrees)
var  aspect = 1.0;       // Viewport aspect ratio

var modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;
var modelViewMatrixLoc, projectionMatrixLoc;
var eye;
const at = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const up = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

var vertices = [
    vec3(0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886),
    vec3(0.0, -0.2722, -0.5773),
    vec3(-0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886),
    vec3(0.5, -0.5443, 0.0)
]

var vertexColors = [
    [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // black
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // red
    [ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // yellow
    [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]  // green

];

window.onload = function init()
{
    
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );
    
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    
    aspect =  canvas.width/canvas.height;
    
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    
    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );
    
    colorPyramid();

    var cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    
    var vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor);

    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    
    var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
    
    modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "modelViewMatrix" );
    projectionMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "projectionMatrix" );

// sliders for viewing parameters

    document.getElementById("zFarSlider").onchange = function() {
        far = event.srcElement.value;
    };
    document.getElementById("zNearSlider").onchange = function() {
        near = event.srcElement.value;
    };
    document.getElementById("radiusSlider").onchange = function() {
       radius = event.srcElement.value;
    };
    document.getElementById("thetaSlider").onchange = function() {
        theta = event.srcElement.value* Math.PI/180.0;
    };
    document.getElementById("phiSlider").onchange = function() {
        phi = event.srcElement.value* Math.PI/180.0;
    };
    document.getElementById("aspectSlider").onchange = function() {
        aspect = event.srcElement.value;
    };
    document.getElementById("fovSlider").onchange = function() {
        fovy = event.srcElement.value;
    };

    render();
}

function colorPyramid()
{
    quad( 0, 1, 2 ); // bottom
    quad( 1, 0, 3 ); // side0
    quad( 1, 2, 3 ); // side1
    quad( 2, 0, 3 ); // side3

}

function quad(a, b, c) 
{

    var indices = [ a, b, c];
    var ndx = pointsArray.length % vertexColors.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i ) {
        pointsArray.push( vertices[indices[i]] );

        colorsArray.push(vertexColors[ndx]);
        
    }
}

function render()
{
    // gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    theta[axis] += 2.0;
    // gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    // gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    // requestAnimFrame( render );
       gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            
    eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.cos(phi), 
    radius*Math.sin(theta)*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.cos(theta));
    modelViewMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);
    projectionMatrix = perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix) );
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projectionMatrixLoc, false, flatten(projectionMatrix) );
            
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

```html
<div>
zNear .01<input id="zNearSlider" type="range"
 min=".01" max="3" step="0.1" value="0.3" />
 3
</div>
<div>
zFar 3<input id="zFarSlider" type="range"
 min="3" max="10" step="3.0" value="3" />
 10
</div>
<div>
radius 0.05<input id="radiusSlider" type="range"
 min="0.05" max="10" step="0.1" value="4" />
 10
</div>
<div>
theta -90<input id="thetaSlider" type="range"
 min="-90" max="90" step="5" value="0" />
 90
</div>
<div>
phi -90<input id="phiSlider" type="range"
 min="-90" max="90" step="5" value="0" />
 90
</div>
<div>
fov 10<input id="fovSlider" type="range"
 min="10" max="120" step="5" value="45" />
 120
</div>
<div>
aspect 0.5<input id="aspectSlider" type="range"
 min="0.5" max="2" step="0.1" value="1" />
 2
</div>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 theta;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main() 
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    <!-- vec3 angles = radians( theta ); -->
    <!-- vec3 c = cos( angles ); -->
    <!-- vec3 s = sin( angles ); -->

    <!-- // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major -->
    <!-- mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, -->
            <!-- 0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0, -->
            <!-- 0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0, -->
            <!-- 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 ); -->

    <!-- mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0, -->
            <!-- 0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, -->
            <!-- s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0, -->
            <!-- 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 ); -->


    <!-- mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, -s.z, 0.0, 0.0, -->
            <!-- s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0, -->
            <!-- 0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -->
            <!-- 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ); -->

    <!-- fColor = vColor; -->
    <!-- gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition; -->
    
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vPosition;
    fColor = vColor;
} 
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;
   
varying vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>

<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Pyramid.js"></script>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512"" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
   
<br/>

<button id= "xButton">Rotate X</button>
<button id= "yButton">Rotate Y</button>
<button id= "zButton">Rotate Z</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues

1. `<!-- ... -->` are not valid comments inside GLSL shaders. Use `/* ... */` or `//
2. The code had a size of 4 for positions when calling `gl.vertexAttribPointer`. It needed to be 3.
3. The code had 2 variables called `theta`. One a number, the other an array, the code tries to use them both ways. One way to avoid this issue is use `let` instead of `var`. `var` is basically deprecated at this point. With `let` you'd have gotten an error.  Also put `"use strict";` at the top of your JavaScript. It will help find more errors. I renamed one of them theta2
4. The pyramid is 4 units from the view but far plane of the frustum is set to 3 so the pyramid is outside the frustum
5. The rotation of the view is rotated by +2 each frame but rotation is in radians so +2 is about 1/3 the way around so it would rotate way too fast.

```js
'use strict';
let canvas;
let gl;

let NumVertices  = 12;

let pointsArray = [];
let colorsArray = [];

let xAxis = 0;
let yAxis = 1;
let zAxis = 2;

let axis = 0;
let theta = [ 0, 0, 0 ];

let near = 0.3;
let far = 10.0;
let radius = 4.0;
let theta2  = 0.0;
let phi    = 0.0;
let dr = 5.0 * Math.PI/180.0;

//var thetaLoc;

let  fovy = 45.0;  // Field-of-view in Y direction angle (in degrees)
let  aspect = 1.0;       // Viewport aspect ratio

let modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix;
let modelViewMatrixLoc, projectionMatrixLoc;
let eye;
const at = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
const up = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

var vertices = [
    vec3(0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886),
    vec3(0.0, -0.2722, -0.5773),
    vec3(-0.5, -0.2722, 0.2886),
    vec3(0.5, -0.5443, 0.0)
]

var vertexColors = [
    [ 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // black
    [ 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // red
    [ 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ],  // yellow
    [ 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ]  // green

];

window.onload = function init()
{
    
    canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );
    
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
    if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

    gl.viewport( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height );
    
    aspect =  canvas.width/canvas.height;
    
    gl.clearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    
    //
    //  Load shaders and initialize attribute buffers
    //
    let program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
    gl.useProgram( program );
    
    colorPyramid();

    let cBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, cBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colorsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    
    let vColor = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vColor" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vColor, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vColor);

    let vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW );
    
    let vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
    gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );
    
    modelViewMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "modelViewMatrix" );
    projectionMatrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation( program, "projectionMatrix" );

// sliders for viewing parameters

    document.getElementById("zFarSlider").onchange = function() {
        far = event.srcElement.value;
    };
    document.getElementById("zNearSlider").onchange = function() {
        near = event.srcElement.value;
    };
    document.getElementById("radiusSlider").onchange = function() {
       radius = event.srcElement.value;
    };
    document.getElementById("thetaSlider").onchange = function() {
        theta2 = event.srcElement.value* Math.PI/180.0;
    };
    document.getElementById("phiSlider").onchange = function() {
        phi = event.srcElement.value* Math.PI/180.0;
    };
    document.getElementById("aspectSlider").onchange = function() {
        aspect = event.srcElement.value;
    };
    document.getElementById("fovSlider").onchange = function() {
        fovy = event.srcElement.value;
    };

    render();
}

function colorPyramid()
{
    quad( 0, 1, 2 ); // bottom
    quad( 1, 0, 3 ); // side0
    quad( 1, 2, 3 ); // side1
    quad( 2, 0, 3 ); // side3

}

function quad(a, b, c) 
{

    let indices = [ a, b, c];
    let ndx = pointsArray.length % vertexColors.length;
    for ( let i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i ) {
        pointsArray.push( vertices[indices[i]] );

        colorsArray.push(vertexColors[ndx]);
        
    }
}

function render()
{
    // gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    theta[axis] += 2.0;
    theta2 += .02;
    // gl.uniform3fv(thetaLoc, theta);

    // gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );

    // requestAnimFrame( render );
       gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            
    eye = vec3(radius*Math.sin(theta2)*Math.cos(phi), 
    radius*Math.sin(theta2)*Math.sin(phi), radius*Math.cos(theta2));
    modelViewMatrix = lookAt(eye, at , up);
    projectionMatrix = perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far);

    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( modelViewMatrixLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix) );
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv( projectionMatrixLoc, false, flatten(projectionMatrix) );
            
    gl.drawArrays( gl.TRIANGLES, 0, NumVertices );
    requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

```html
<div>
zNear .01<input id="zNearSlider" type="range"
 min=".01" max="3" step="0.1" value="0.3" />
 3
</div>
<div>
zFar 3<input id="zFarSlider" type="range"
 min="3" max="10" step="3.0" value="3" />
 10
</div>
<div>
radius 0.05<input id="radiusSlider" type="range"
 min="0.05" max="10" step="0.1" value="4" />
 10
</div>
<div>
theta -90<input id="thetaSlider" type="range"
 min="-90" max="90" step="5" value="0" />
 90
</div>
<div>
phi -90<input id="phiSlider" type="range"
 min="-90" max="90" step="5" value="0" />
 90
</div>
<div>
fov 10<input id="fovSlider" type="range"
 min="10" max="120" step="5" value="45" />
 120
</div>
<div>
aspect 0.5<input id="aspectSlider" type="range"
 min="0.5" max="2" step="0.1" value="1" />
 2
</div>
<script id="vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

attribute  vec4 vPosition;
attribute  vec4 vColor;
varying vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 theta;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main() 
{
    // Compute the sines and cosines of theta for each of
    //   the three axes in one computation.
    //<!-- vec3 angles = radians( theta ); -->
    //<!-- vec3 c = cos( angles ); -->
    //<!-- vec3 s = sin( angles ); -->

    //<!-- // Remeber: thse matrices are column-major -->
    //<!-- mat4 rx = mat4( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0, 0.0, -->
    //        <!-- 0.0,  c.x,  s.x, 0.0, -->
    //        <!-- 0.0, -s.x,  c.x, 0.0, -->
    //        <!-- 0.0,  0.0,  0.0, 1.0 ); -->

    //<!-- mat4 ry = mat4( c.y, 0.0, -s.y, 0.0, -->
    //        <!-- 0.0, 1.0,  0.0, 0.0, -->
    //        <!-- s.y, 0.0,  c.y, 0.0, -->
    //        <!-- 0.0, 0.0,  0.0, 1.0 ); -->


    //<!-- mat4 rz = mat4( c.z, -s.z, 0.0, 0.0, -->
    //        <!-- s.z,  c.z, 0.0, 0.0, -->
    //        <!-- 0.0,  0.0, 1.0, 0.0, -->
    //        <!-- 0.0,  0.0, 0.0, 1.0 ); -->

    //<!-- fColor = vColor; -->
    //<!-- gl_Position = rz * ry * rx * vPosition; -->
    
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vPosition;
    fColor = vColor;
} 
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

precision mediump float;
   
varying vec4 fColor;

void
main()
{
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>

<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/MV.js"></script>

<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512"" height="512">
Oops ... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element
</canvas>
   
<br/>

<button id= "xButton">Rotate X</button>
<button id= "yButton">Rotate Y</button>
<button id= "zButton">Rotate Z</button>
```

Other tips

1. Learn how to use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)
2. Make your code runnable by linking to the libraries you use

```
    <script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/initShaders.js"></script>
    <script src="https://esangel.github.io/WebGL/Common/MV.js"></script>
```

3. Consider adding [webgl-lint](https://greggman.github.io/webgl-lint/) to help find errors.
4. Learn from some different [lessons](https://webglfundamentals.org).